# Are the below answers eligible for selection?

Tags: sql, oracle

So this is actually regarding some interview questionare which i was asked. Purely related to Oracle Pl/sql.

Ques1) Lets say i have an employee table i have to get the manager name for each employee?

```
Empid    name manageridsal

1        a     3       100
2        b     3       100
3        c     4       200
4        d     null    400
```

So what i wrote was

```
 Select e1.*,e2.name as managername
 From table e1 join
 table e2 on
 e1.empid=e2.managerid
```

And the second was to get avg(sal) of manager and all other employees

```
 Select managerid, 
 Avg(sal) from table
 Group by managerid
 Union
 Select ,empid
 Avg(sal) from table
 Where empid not in
 (select managerid 
  From table) 
 Group by empid


   Empid        avg sal
   1                 100
   2                 100
   3                 200
   4                 300
```

But as per interviewer's look i had got a pretty good idea that i din met what he actually expected even i thought somewhere the same. Just wanna know are these answers liable.

Comment: I think you got `e1` and `e2` reversed in the first query.

Comment: What's the expected result of the second question?

Comment: Expected the only 3rd employee  has 150. Even i wasnt sure what interviewer mean he just made up this question and i was unsure

Comment: Right, but please add the resulting table with actual values into the question. It's not clear to me what the result *should* be.

Comment: In actual i think it should be 200 and 600 for employee 3 and 4 rest same salary as avg salary as they are employees not managers.

Comment: Thanks impalar for the first answer yes i now realized that i made a silly mistake of reversing the join columns

Comment: There is no PL/SQL in these questions. They appear to be about SQL only.

Comment: The final query will only show totals for managers 3, 4 and null. The `not in ()` part of the query will return no rows.

Comment: How come these 2 queries are separate n then unioned. The output would be for all ids the only thing is salary of managers would be avg sal of employees under them or did u mean because of null you can ignore that i can have where manager id is not null in that same subquery

Answer (score 1):

In the first query, you need to switch the columns in the join condition: otherwise, you are bringing all *managees* of the current employee instead of their *manager*.

```
select e1.*,e2.name as managername
from table e1 
left join table e2 on e2.empid = e1.managerid
```

When it comes to the second question: I am unsure about what you mean by *avg(sal) of manager and all other employees*. You might need to provide sample data for this.

Comment: Yeah correct GMB now. Also did u look at my 2nd answer also. Just that i had less time to solve these i made these errors cant do much about it now

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja: you would need to edit your question to show us the desired result for the second question.

Comment: Edited check now also but interviewer gave me wrong results thats y i was not sure as he said for 3rd 150 should be there but in actual if should include his own salary + avg(sal) from employee under him